# Python: fetch multiply text value from webpage

Tags: python, html

I have one internal website, will publish the latest statistics in daily basis.
This website has information about many companies. I need to get one company's data.
The HTML code is like following:

*Note: All text values, like "Big Company A", "1810", "14", "2045", "135", "98.8%", "100.0%" are all required to be output.*

****Note 2: There are many Companies list in the same page, they are all with the same structure. the problem for me is, how to locate "Big Company A", and output all Text value belong to Big Company A?***

```
<TH class=Company><A href="?scope=1&amp;values=1&amp;deleg=35">Big Company A</A></TH>
<TD>1810</TD>
<TD>14</TD>
<TD>2045</TD>
<TD>135</TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="av_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">99.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="av_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="hips_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="hips_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">98.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="os_reportbyou.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%&amp;server=0&amp;counts=1">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="os_reportbyou.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%&amp;server=1&amp;counts=1">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">95.7%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">97.6%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">104.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">104.2%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">99.9%</A></TD>
```

Sorry to that I do not have much knowledge on Python and HTML, Thanks for your help in advance

***Edit note***
@2014/04/01, Append one comment regarding how to locate "Big Company A'.

Comment: Have a look at beautiful soup.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, I checked BeautifulSoup, and I think I need put more time to learn about HTML and Python

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you want the output of the code to be. Do you want it to be all of the values contained within the  tags, or just the values that you wrote in the question?

If it's the former, then you can easily use BeautifulSoup to get all the data.

```
html = #your html 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
list = soup.findAll("td")
for thing in list: 
    print list.text
```

I haven't checked this code, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, It's close to what I want. and there is another problem to locate "Big Company A", since we have same structure for other company, I need to locate "Big Company A", and output the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) parser, iterate over every tag on a page and get the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<TH class="Company">
<A href="?scope=1&amp;values=1&amp;deleg=35">Big Company A</A>
</TH>
<TD>1810</TD>
<TD>14</TD>
<TD>2045</TD>
<TD>135</TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="av_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">99.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="av_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="hips_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="hips_report.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">98.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="os_reportbyou.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%&amp;server=0&amp;counts=1">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="os_reportbyou.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%&amp;server=1&amp;counts=1">100.0%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">95.7%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">97.6%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">104.8%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">104.2%</A></TD>
<TD class=ok><A class=ok href="pa_reportbydelegs4.php?deleg=35&amp;dc=%&amp;ou=%&amp;bu=%&amp;site=%">99.9%</A></TD>
</TH>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for tag in soup:
    print tag.text
```

prints:

```
Big Company A

1810
14
2045
135
99.8%
100.0%
100.0%
98.8%
100.0%
100.0%
95.7%
97.6%
104.8%
104.2%
99.9%
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, your code is simple and effective, I like it. And there is another question is to locate "big company A" and output the same value. I have tried to figure it out, but without any progress.